# How to shutdown a neo4j DB after creation by BatchImporter?

Tags: neo4j

I have used https://github.com/jexp/batch-import to create my `neo4j` db.
after download, I unzipped, then opened a command line in the folder, wrote `"import.bat test.db nodes.csv rels.csv"`.

It imported my db successfully with no errors. Now I want access to `test.db` by `neo4j` browser but the error by that is

```
"Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting
org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase,
C:\Users\NP\Documents\Neo4j\test.db".
```

I know that `neo4j` is a `single user soft`,but it seems that the batch importer can't close db so the db is not going to be used anywhere. I don't know how to close or shutdown that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new import tool in neo4j 2.2.x, http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html would you mind trying that instead?